# Prove that $P(A ∩ B) ≤ P(A ∪ B) ≤ P(A) + P(B)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I don´t know if my proof is right. I separated it into 2:

$1) P(A ∩ B) ≤ P(A ∪ B)$

Pf: 
$P(A ∪ B) = P(A\setminus B) + P(B\setminus A) + P(A ∩ B)$
and we know that $0 ≤ P(A\setminus B) ≤ 1$ and $0 ≤ P(B\setminus A) ≤ 1$
so $P(A ∩ B) ≤ P(A ∪ B)$

$2)  P(A ∪ B) ≤ P(A) + P(B)$

Pf: 
$P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)$
and we know that $0 ≤ P(A ∩ B) ≤ 1$
so $P(A ∪ B) ≤ P(A) + P(B)$

Therefore, $P(A ∩ B) ≤ P(A ∪ B) ≤ P(A) + P(B)$

Comment: What does $P(X)$ mean?  The power set of $X$?  The probability of an event $X$?  What does P(X) \le P(Y)$ mean?

Comment: @fleablood from context, $P(X)$ is clearly referring to probability and $\le$ means the usual less than or equal relation on real numbers.  @ Regina, you have some misused symbols.  Set difference is `\ `, not to be confused with `/` which is more often for division or quotient groups etc...  Visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site.

Comment: If you use Venn diagram the problem will simplify and you will be able to visualize better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine. In the first proof you are really making use of the fact that 
$
P(A\setminus B)\geq 0
$
and $P(B\setminus A)\geq 0$. In the second proof you are making use of the fact that $P(A\cap B)\geq 0$. You aren't really making use of the fact that the probabilities are at most one so I would omit it from the explanation.